# How do I pass objects between classes

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to encapsulate a Selenium script by breaking it up into three classes (Grid, Browser, and testCase). I'm able to get the browser to open, but I seem to be missing the connection for the testCase class to interject its commands.

Grid.java

```
package com.autotrader.grid;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Grid {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    TestCase testCase = new TestCase();

    public Grid() {
        browser.setUp("http://pbskids.org");
    }

    @Test
    public void main() {
        testCase.runCase();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        browser.stop();
    }
}
```

Browser.java

```
package com.autotrader.grid;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Browser {

    private String baseUrl;
    private String driverNamespace;
    private String driverLocation;

    private DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    private WebDriver driver;
    public Selenium selenium;

    // constructor
    public Browser() {

    }

    public DesiredCapabilities getCapabilities() {
        return this.capabilities;
    }

    public String getDriverLocation() {
        return this.driverLocation;
    }

    public String getDriverNamespace() {
        return this.driverNamespace;
    }

    public Selenium getSelenium(){
        return selenium;
    }

    public void open (String url) {
        this.selenium.open(url);
    }

    public void setBaseUrl(String url) {
        this.baseUrl = url;
    }

    public void setCapabilities() {
        this.capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    }

    public void setDriverLocation(String location) {
        this.driverLocation = location;
    }

    public void setDriverNamespace(String namespace) {
        this.driverNamespace = namespace;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed){
        this.selenium.setSpeed(speed);
    }

    public void setUp(String url){
        setDriverNamespace("webdriver.firefox.driver");
        setDriverLocation(System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") + "\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty(driverNamespace,driverLocation);

        setCapabilities();
        setBaseUrl(url);

        this.selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, url);
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void stop(){
        this.selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

TestCase.java

```
package com.autotrader.grid;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class TestCase {

    Browser browser = new Browser();
    Selenium selenium;

    // constructor
    public TestCase(){
        selenium = browser.getSelenium();
    }

    public void runCase(){
        selenium.open("/privacy/termsofuse.html?campaign=fkhp_tou");
        selenium.setSpeed("1000");
    }
}
```

So; the driver is setup, I then opened using the Selenium object (in Browser.java), but when I try to interact with the Selenium object (in TestCase.java) it's not picking it up. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
public class Grid {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    TestCase testCase = new TestCase();

    public Grid() {
    ...
```

Try:

```
public class Grid {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    TestCase testCase = new TestCase(browser); // <-- this line changed

    public Grid() {
    ...
```

And in here:

```
public class TestCase {

    Browser browser = new Browser();
    Selenium selenium;

    // constructor
    public TestCase(){
        selenium = browser.getSelenium();
    }
    ...
```

Do like this:

```
public class TestCase {

    Browser browser = new Browser();             // <-- this line changed
    Selenium selenium;

    // constructor
    public TestCase(Browser browser){            // <-- this line changed
        this.browser = browser;                  // <-- this line was added
        selenium = browser.getSelenium();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. The only thing I did different was to declare TestCase in the main function of Grid.class. I noticed if I declared it outside then the browser object wouldn't have all the values attached to setUp().

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you're ever initializing your Selenium object except for in Browser's `setUp(String url)` method.  And that method is also not being called here.

You've also made your Browser's Selenium object public, so you don't need to declare another Selenium object in TestCase that's assigned by an accessor method -- you can just reference it from TestCase's Browser object.

Comment: Originally I made it public to simply use it across classes, but I never figured out how to apply it properly. I set it back to private.